Widespread use of non-portable `void **` casts
I believe the following code is well-defined according to the C standard:
void f(void **);
void *p;
f((void **)&p);

But what if p isn't a pointer to void, say:
void f(void **);
double *p;
f((void **)&p);

According to the C FAQ, it is not portable. However, it does not cause my compiler to emit any warnings, and searching well known C codebases yields many instances of such non-void *-casts, for example Linux, CPython, and COM all do it. The answers of the most closely related SO question that I could find make no mention of this being strange or nonstandard. So, is this usage of void ** really non-portable? And if so why does it seem to be common practice?

As the answer says, it may work, but is not guaranteed. So it is up to you, the developer, to handle any cases where it may not work.


You used a cast, so the compiler assumes you know what you are doing. 2. The C standard does not define this behaviour, but it is mostly portable in practice.


It depends on what you do with the pointers inside and outside f. A void * is compatible with any pointer type, but when assigning to void * you lose the information about the data type or object size. void ** allows f to modify the pointer p. In the 2nd case it is undefined behavior if f assigns a value which is not a valid pointer to double. In the first case you must use it as a pointer to the same data type inside and outside f. With casts or void*, the programmer is responsible for making sure everything is correct. The compiler might not warn you if it's wrong.

It is non-portable, but COM can use it because the ABI requirements of COM are stricter than C. I suspect similar remarks apply to linux. Not sure about CPython.

To make things more interesting, POSIX states that *(void **)(&cosine)=dlsym(handle, "cos") is the correct way to assign a function pointer from dlsym.

The cast in the first snippet is not necessary; &p is a void ** already, so the cast merely obfuscates what you're doing.  I deal with second scenario using: double *p = …; void *vp = p; f(&vp); p = vp; because the most plausible reason for passing the double pointer is that the called code is going to modify the pointer it is given.  If p is uninitialized, then use double *p; void *vp = NULL; f(&vp); p = vp;.

It is undefined behaviour to dereference the resulting void **, so you might as well use a void *.
double *p;
void **vp = (void **)p;  // UB if it violates alignment restrictions.
*vp = NULL;              // Dereferencing `vp` is UB.


If void * and double * have different alignment restrictions, the behaviour is undefined. It is otherwise allowed.

C17 §6.3.2.3 ¶7 A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

So the cast itself should be safe in most environments. But what if you dereference the void **?
This is a "strict aliasing violation" and thus undefined behaviour.

C17 §6.5 ¶7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the
following types:

a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective
type of the object,
an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members
(including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
a character type.



Is there any case where void **vp = (void **)p; would violate alignment restrictions? Don't see why two different pointers would be aligned differently

@Ted Klein Bergman That would be rare, if it exists. That's why I said it would be safe in most environments. Maybe a system where void * is larger than a double *.

Actually the cast is wrong and non-portable but most compilers can't even detect the problem.
Suppose we have a word-addressed architecture but double is 80 bits long and uses partial words. (This is far more likely with char or long double than double I digress.)
We may end up with sizeof(int *) == 4 but sizeof(double *) == 8; therefore sizeof(void *) must also be 8; however sizeof (void **) can easily be 4.
This results in function f shearing part of the pointer off and the code not working. A compiler for a platform that actually exhibits this behavior would successfully warn against this; however most compilers only target architectures for which all pointer sizes are the same and don't have a way of detecting the problem.
Platforms that behave like this are mostly gone and nobody outside of the embedded world cares. The only one I have ever encountered was nasty and completely nonportable because const void * and void * were different sizes due to the fact that ROM was bigger than the CPU's word size but RAM was not.
While this particular sample tends to work; most examples of this form are also unstable due to violating the strict aliasing rule.

Note that hardware considerations are not the only reason a C program may fail when there is undefined behavior. Even if double * and void * have exactly the same size and representation, a compiler may in various situations, take as a premise that a d of type double ** and a v of type void ** do not point at the same memory, due to the rules about aliasing, and therefore *d = foo; bar = *v; may be reordered during optimization. This is just one example.

@EricPostpischil: This is true; I failed to construct a live example from the fragment provided. In other cases (for example, the pointer not being a local variable) it is likely to fail as you describe.

You might mention that the POSIX Standard mandates that all pointer types have the same size and representation, hence the cast cannot have the adverse side effect you illustrate.  Yet the strict aliasing violation might cause very nasty bugs in code that uses such casts: this explains why compilers have become much more voiceful under elevated warning levels about innocent looking but potentially harmful code, even on POSIX compliant systems.

@chqrlie: Not much point. What would actually happen on such a platform is the standard would step aside. We've seen it before.

@chqrlie "POSIX Standard mandates that all pointer types have the same size" is interesting.  Do you have a cite?

@chux: I cannot remember where I saw this assertion.  I did find this Pointer Types POSIX.1-2008 explicitly requires implementations to convert pointers to void * and back with no loss of information. This is an extension over the ISO C standard. Which almost implies that data pointers must be at least as large as function pointers, thereby excluding the ancient x86 Compact Model.

@chux: note also that all pointers to structures must have the same size to allow code handling incomplete types to compile.  The same constraint applies to pointers to union types.
